# how to evaluate junit.xml using phing

Tags: php, cakephp, junit, phpunit, phing

I am using phing to build my CakePHP web application.

I want to have a phing target that goes along these lines:

1. Run the test suite
2. if there is even 1 failure, end the phing target
3. if all okay, run the command "git commit -a"

For my test suite, I follow the CakePHP convention which uses PHPUnit

```
${cake} testsuite ${runinworkspaceapp} app AllTests --log-junit ${builddir}/logs/junit.xml
```

where

- `${cake}` simply means `${appdir}/Console/cake`
- `${runinworkspaceapp}` means `-app ${appdir}`

I will generate a junit.xml file. Below is a snippet of the junit.xml

```
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="All Tests" tests="44" assertions="373" failures="0" errors="0" time="4.634020">
    <testsuite name="All Model related class tests" tests="42" assertions="370" failures="0" errors="0" time="4.478717">
```

I suspect that I need to evaluate the junit.xml file in order to tell whether there is any error. I could be wrong and there is a better way.

**How do I write the phing target?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake should exit with an `exit code != 0` when at least one test failed, so using `<exec>` with `checkreturn="true"` should suffice.

---

`junit.xml` can be converted to HTML with a phing task (also see http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/visualizing-phpunit-runs.htm):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="testreport" default="gen-report" basedir=".">
 <target name="gen-report">
  <phpunitreport infile="log.junit.xml"
                 format="frames"
                 todir="html"
                 styledir="/usr/share/php/data/phing/etc/"
                 />
 </target>
</project>
```

Comment: I don't understand how this converstion to HTML can help me inform Phing not to run `git commit -a` when there is a failure.

Comment: http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/chapters/appendixes/AppendixB-CoreTasks.html for exectask there is no failonerror unfortunately

Comment: okay it works but please change yes to true. cause it is boolean